# taking snapshots of a BTRFS volume mounted with nodatacow?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, snapshot

I plan to create two subvolumes on a BTRFS-formatted spinning disk. I plan to mount one of those subvolumes with nodatacow so that I can efficiently store virtual machine images and database files there.

Is there any problem using snapper to enable snapshots of the subvolume mounted with nodatacow?

What should I be aware of when taking snapshots of volumes that don't use COW?

All I have found so far is a sentence in the BTRFS FAQ:

> Can copy-on-write be turned off for data blocks?
>
> Yes, there are several ways how to do that.
>
> Disable it by mounting with nodatacow. This implies nodatasum as well.
>   **COW may still happen if a snapshot is taken.**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Regarding the *nodatacow* option, Ohad Rodeh's paper titled [BTRFS: The Linux B-tree Filesystem](https://sites.google.com/site/ohadrodehshomepage/research) states:

> It cancels copy-on-write for data blocks, unless there is a snapshot.

There is no problem with creating a snapshot of a subvolume mounted with *nodatacow*. But since cow is required to create a snapshot, when you create one on a subvolume with *nodatacow* it will essentially ignore *nodatacow*; acting as it normally would.

That does however bring up an interesting question: Is the *nodatacow* ignored permanently? Does creating a snapshot of a subvolume with COW disabled, reenable COW until it's manually disabled again?

Luckily, no. From the btrfs [mailing list](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg33090.html)...

> On a NOCOW file the first write to a fileblock (4096 bytes) after a 
>   snapshot must still be COW, because the snapshot locks the old version
>   in  place, and now the fileblock has changed, so it MUST be written
>   elsewhere  despite the NOCOW in ordered to keep the snapshot as it
>   was.  However,  the file does retain the NOCOW attribute and
>   additional writes to the  same fileblock will be in-place... until the
>   next snapshot of course.

Comment: It's unclear to me from the link whether it's the _original volume_ or the _snapshot_ which becomes COW? i.e. if I only take **read-only** snapshots for backup purposes, does that mean that the original volume will continue honouring `nodatacow`? Or does that mean that the original volume is not "... NOCOW on the first write after a snapshot", forever?

Comment: @Luciano The first write on the original volume after snapshoting must be COWed. But the subsequent writes on the that same volume will honor NOCOW again.

Comment: Will COW still happen if all the snapshots of the sub-volume have been removed ? Or if no write happen while the snapshot lives ?